# How can I save the output of command ands its 'time' of execution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a command and get its output and the time it took to run the command

```
TIMEFORMAT='real %3R'
VAR1=$( time command );
```

When I echo VAR1 it shows the time and command output. But I can't seem to extract the time substring. I've tried with grep, sed and cut. Any tip for this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output you get and which is the bash you're using?
On my mac i get time as not really part of the output but after.

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='real %3R'
$ time ls|tail -0
real 0.018
$ VAR=$(time ls|tail -0)
real 0.006
$ echo $VAR
```

I'm using
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try the external version of the time utility. There's an --output=file option to let you save stats separate from your program's output. A typical location is: /usr/bin/time